# Swift: Rotating UIImage and filling it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image-processing, uiimage

I am currently working on rotating an image and filling it with swift.
If I use the code below (which I got from the internet) I can rotate an image, keeping size.
An example is illustrated below the code.
And, the problem is, I have a gray gap in every corner after the rotation.
I want to fill it with white so that image looks nice.

**Is there any way to fill the gap after the rotation in swift?**

Thank you!

```
extension UIImage {

    func rotatedBy(degree: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let radian = -degree * CGFloat.pi / 180
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.translateBy(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        context.rotate(by: radian)
        context.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: -(self.size.width / 2), y: -(self.size.height / 2), width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))

        let rotatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return rotatedImage
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: What if the image is a picture or the background is not white?

Comment: In the app I am making, all background is white. So, it wont be a problem. Besides, I also want to know the general way to fill color in swift, so any answer would help!

Comment: So just set the color to white and fill it before drawing your image

Comment: Thank you! If possible, I would like to know what sort of code to use. But still, your answer helped a lot! :)

Comment: is it context.setFillColor() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set a fill color and fill your context before rotating the image:

---

```
extension UIImage {
    func rotatedBy(degree: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return nil }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        context.fill(.init(origin: .zero, size: size))
        context.translateBy(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
        context.rotate(by: -degree * .pi / 180)
        context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(origin: .init(x: -size.width/2, y: -size.height/2), size: size))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```